# Margenes de impresión vb.net

Tags: vb.net, impresión

necesito apoyo en este tema ya que he tratado con muchos cambios pero no se están aplicando los margenes que necesito.
Tengo este codigo de Print Document en vb.net
Genero una etiqueta con dimensiones de 3.5" de ancho x 1" de alto, incluso al forzar o sin forzar ese tamaño imprime correcto ya que esta definido en la impresora ese tamaño de papel hasta cierto punto, son 5 lineas que entran en la etiqueta con el Font de arial 12,  entonces al mandar a imprimir el textbox la linea 4 sale a la mitad he visto el margen y en top aparece en 100 y bot 0, he tratado de manipular con diferentes formas pero no logro que se cambie los margenes, todo lo demas si esta en orden.

```
Private Sub PrintDocument1_PrintPage(sender As Object, e As Printing.PrintPageEventArgs) Handles PrintDocument1.PrintPage

Dim printsize As Size = e.MarginBounds.Size
        Dim printpage As Size = e.PageBounds.Size
        Dim printFont As Font = New Font("Arial", 12, FontStyle.Bold)
        Dim printFont2 As Font = New Font("Arial", 14, FontStyle.Bold)
        Dim texto As String = ""
        texto += EtiquetaBox.Text
        Dim x As Single = 2.0F
        printsize.Width *= 3.5
        printsize.Height *= 1
       
        MessageBox.Show(e.MarginBounds.Size.ToString & " " & e.MarginBounds.Top.ToString)
e.Graphics.DrawString(texto, printFont, Brushes.Black, x, -2)
 End Sub

Private Sub ImprBTN_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ImprBTN.Click
        PrintDocument1.Print()
    End Sub2
```

Comment: Al Parecer el Printable area me esta dejando el 66.66% del alto, habra una forma de modificarlo?

Comment: En efecto aunque envíes el dato del margen, y demás configuraciones en la Impresora Epson FX-2190 no toma en cuenta el Margen ya que crea una inconsistencia el Bottom Margin con el que tiene definido la impresora y cae en offset por lo cual vuelve a establecer un default que es de 66.66% como si fuera de una hoja tamaño A4, a lo cual la solución es forzar en la impresora el margen mínimo disponible para el tamaño de 1 pulgada y jugando con las configuraciones es .10 hasta .13 para tener un buen margen al final y no se desfase entre series de impresiones.

Answer (score 0):

En efecto aunque envíes el dato del margen, y demás configuraciones en la Impresora Epson FX-2190 no toma en cuenta el Margen ya que crea una inconsistencia el Bottom Margin con el que tiene definido la impresora y cae en offset por lo cual vuelve a establecer un default que es de 66.66% como si fuera de una hoja tamaño A4, a lo cual la solución es forzar en la impresora el margen mínimo disponible para el tamaño de 1 pulgada y jugando con las configuraciones es .10 hasta .13 para tener un buen margen al final y no se desfase entre series de impresiones.